# Convert a Yahoo account to a Delicious account

Tags: yahoo, delicious

I use Delicious + the Firefox extension to manage my bookmarks.
Unfortunately, my Delicious account is plugged to my Yahoo account, which can stay logged in for only two weeks, keeps asking me to change my password and secret question quite often, and requires to login in a separate page.

See the login page here: https://secure.delicious.com/login?jump=ub

I have to use my Yahoo ID to log in, which is really annoying.
I would like to switch back to a default Delicious account. Is it possible?

Comment: I have used the official Delicious extension for a long time, and it has never asked me to login again.

Comment: I use it on different PCs (work and home), and I have to log in each time I switch :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found my answer here:
http://support.delicious.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=3581

All new accounts must use Yahoo's login system.